# one database in phpmyadmin for 2 website

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

please help

before ask my hosting limits the addition of the database (I mean hosting that I use can only add 1 database only)

i want to ask, how to one database in phpmyadmin for 2 website?

2 website i use wordpress sir

can 1 database for 2 website sir? how to sir?

sorry instead i do not want to upgrade to better package hosting
but I want to know, is there any other way that 1 database can be used for 2 wordpress website

please help

thanks before

Comment: Not a programming question, so you are off-topic. (but you can: just use different prefixes)

Comment: "put on hold as unclear what you're asking" ? What ? This man just want to have two wordpress in one database, what is unclear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use different prefix when you are doing the installation of the wordpress or make the two websites with Wordpress Network functionality.

For the prefix, just replace `wp_` by `website1prefix` for the website 1, and `wp_` by `website2prefix`.

For the network :

https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: this is simply right